# How can I use question mark correctly?

Tags: punctuation

1. What is your father's name, mother's name, and brother's name ?
2. Can you answer the following?
                           Or the following:
3. Are you well?...or not?

Which is\are correct among the three? And please correct my fault.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the one that is complete, correct, and natural.

The second would be correct in either case, though the colon is more natural. However, the list that follows would have to be a list of questions. It could be replaced with "please provide:" and a list of items that aren't questions.

The third will be seen (or at least heard), but it is more correct to say "are you ... or not?", usually used where someone has been asked the question bare and been evasive.